# Which databases can have row and column level security based upon Active Directory?

Tags: security, active-directory, row-level-security

I have various database types, Oracle 11g, MySQL 5, Sql Server 2012.  I have direct access.  I can have other databases if I need them such as PostgreSQL.

What I'm doing is protecting data at the database and table level as opposed to the application level though I there will be some mixing.

What I'm hoping to do is control all the security from Active Directory.  I don't want to do security in MySQL, security in Oracle, etc.  That is a lot of duplicate entry.

I will have a webpage send credentials to the database engine to determine which bits of data the user can see.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for any of the others but as for as SQL Server goes there would be some setup involved but after that you can control security at some level from active directory.

What you would do is create a series of roles (server and database level) and grant them the permissions needed.  Then you would create AD groups and create logins and users based on them.  Then assign those logins and users to the various roles.  Once that is done you can control who has what access by adding and removing individuals from the various AD groups.

There are options for column level permissions and row level permissions can be handled by views.

Now if new objects are created in the database that require additional security then that will have to be managed within SQL server by granting those permissions to the appropriate roles.